# why a public enum type inside a class cannot be initialized in a separate main class?

Tags: java, error-handling, enums, declaration

```
public class Temperature {

    private int id;
    private Type type;
    private int temperature;

    public Temperature(int id, int temp, Type t) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = t;
        this.temperature = temp;
    }

}
```

```
public enum Type {
    CELSIUS("C"), FAHRENHEIT("F");
    private String type;

    private Type(String t) {
        this.type = t;
    }
}
```

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temperature t = new Temperature(1, 36, Type.CELSIUS);
    }
}
```

Here are three separate files with Temperature.java, Type.java and Main.java but if the enum type declared inside the Temperature.java, there is an error when i initialize the temperature object in the main.java, why is that? If we use for these 3 separate files, there is no error.

Comment: You need to specify *what* error.

Answer (score 1):

If the enum is *inside* of Temperature, then it's fully qualified name is `Temperature.Type`. i.e., `Temperature.Type.CELSIUS` and `Temperature.Type.FAHRENHEIT`

e.g.,

if Temperature looks like this:

```
package containingPackage;

public class Temperature {

    private int id;
    private Type type;
    private int temperature;

    public Temperature(int id, int temp, Type t) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = t;
        this.temperature = temp;
    }

    enum Type {
        CELSIUS("C"), FAHRENHEIT("F");
        private String type;

        private Type(String t) {
            this.type = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use the enum, you have to preface it with the Temperature class name:

```
Temperature t = new Temperature(1,36, Temperature.Type.CELSIUS);
```

You can get around this by fully importing the enum:

```
import containingPackage.Temperature.Type;
```

Comment: but the enum type is public, it should not be a problem even though it is declared inside the temperature class?

Comment: @sevenyunan: it's **still** public, but the name-space has changed, that's all. But rather than debate with me, try it and see what happens. If I'm wrong or right, you'll soon find out.

Comment: @sevenyunan: see edit -- note you can get around this by importing the fully qualified enum namespace.